# Swagger showing not existing endpoints. How to get rid of them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm building a really simple REST service in Spring Boot with requests like this:

- GET /api/resources
- POST /api/resources
- GET /api/resources/id
- DELETE /api/resources/id

But when I go to **localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html**, I get a really long list of not existing, redundant endpoints such as:

- DELETE /api/resources
- PATCH /api/resources
- HEAD /api/resources
- OPTIONS /api/resources
- PATCH /api/resources/id
- HEAD /api/resources/id
- OPTIONS /api/resources/id

So, **how to get rid of them**? I've looked for an answer and I only found out how to limit the response list to a specific path, which is not my problem.

I can't hide them via annotation @ApiOperation(value = "xyz", hidden = true), since those requests don't exist in my Controller's code.

Here's my **SwaggerConfig.java** class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(regex("/api.*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

BTW, apparently I get an 404 error on /v2/api-docs, but I don't think that's my problem, since Swagger displays the correct list of endpoints, but also lots of not-existing ones. I haven't found the solution for this 404 error though, but I don't know if I should care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, my Controller code was the problem:

```
 //@RequestMapping("/resource/{id}")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/resource/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Methods in @RequestMapping have to be specified everywhere to get the correct list of endpoints in Swagger, even though the REST service works fine without specifying those sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or you use @GetMapping (obviously for GET methods) or @PostMapping for POST, and you don't need to specify the method.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html